# 'Too many requests' error on Azure IOT central create job API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

Getting the below error in the job api while creating scheduled job for alerts.
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hE3t.png)

Here is the link to Microsoft documentation which states the limit for the requests, but we are creating far less request from application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/throttling

Tried requesting few times, expectation is that Too many requests error should not come

Comment: Agarwal, please provide the details of how u are creating a job in Azure IoT Central using API in a document, link, or GitHub or code. please provide errors in the text, not in the image and please share the code u used, please share it in the above question. How do I ask a good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? How do I create a Minimal, Reproducible [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0):

The below steps below to create a job in IoT Central Application.

**First Create a device in IoT [Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/dataplane/devices/create?view=rest-iotcentral-dataplane-2022-07-31&tabs=HTTP):**

```http
PUT https://{subdomain}.{baseDomain}/api/devices/{deviceId}?api-version=2022-07-31
Authorization:  API tokens
Content-Type: application/json
```

**To create and use an API token:**

- Open your IoT Central application in the browser and go to Permissions > API tokens.
- Click *Generate token*. You'll be prompted to give it a name and choose a role. The role determines what a client using this token is authorized to do in this application.
- Generate the token and copy the value. The value is a secret and will only be shown once.

**Body:**

```json
{
  "displayName": "Device group 1",
  "description": "Custom device group.",
  "filter": "SELECT * FROM devices WHERE $template = \"dtmi:modelDefinition:dtdlv2\" AND $provisioned = true"
}
```

[image]

- Add device templates in Azure IoT Central with the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-manage-device-templates-with-rest-api).

```http
PUT https://{your-app-subdomain}.azureiotcentral.com/api/deviceTemplates/dtmi:contoso:mythermostattemplate;1?api-version=2022-07-31

Authorization:  API tokens
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body:**

```json
{
    "displayName": "Thermostat",
    "@id": "dtmi:contoso:mythermostattemplate;1",
    "@type": [
        "ModelDefinition",
        "DeviceModel"
    ],
    "@context": [
        "dtmi:iotcentral:context;2",
        "dtmi:dtdl:context;2"
    ],
    "capabilityModel": {
        "@id": "dtmi:contoso:Thermostat;1",
        "@type": "Interface",
        "contents": [
            {
                "@type": [
                    "Telemetry",
                    "Temperature"
                ],
                "description": "Temperature in degrees Celsius.",
                "displayName": "Temperature",
                "name": "temperature",
                "schema": "double",
                "unit": "degreeCelsius"
            },
            {
                "@type": [
                    "Property",
                    "Temperature"
                ],
                "description": "Allows to remotely specify the desired target temperature.",
                "displayName": "Target Temperature",
                "name": "targetTemperature",
                "schema": "double",
                "unit": "degreeCelsius",
                "writable": true,
                "decimalPlaces": 1,
                "displayUnit": "C",
                "maxValue": 80,
                "minValue": 50
            },
            {
                "@type": [
                    "Property",
                    "Temperature"
                ],
                "description": "Returns the max temperature since last device reboot.",
                "displayName": "Max temperature since last reboot.",
                "name": "maxTempSinceLastReboot",
                "schema": "double",
                "unit": "degreeCelsius"
            },
            {
                "@type": "Command",
                "description": "This command returns the max, min and average temperature from the specified time to the current time.",
                "displayName": "Get report",
                "name": "getMaxMinReport",
                "request": {
                    "@type": "CommandPayload",
                    "description": "Period to return the max-min report.",
                    "displayName": "Since",
                    "name": "since",
                    "schema": "dateTime"
                },
                "response": {
                    "@type": "CommandPayload",
                    "displayName": "Temperature Report",
                    "name": "tempReport",
                    "schema": {
                        "@type": "Object",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "displayName": "Max temperature",
                                "name": "maxTemp",
                                "schema": "double"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "Min temperature",
                                "name": "minTemp",
                                "schema": "double"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "Average Temperature",
                                "name": "avgTemp",
                                "schema": "double"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "Start Time",
                                "name": "startTime",
                                "schema": "dateTime"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "End Time",
                                "name": "endTime",
                                "schema": "dateTime"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "@type": [
                    "Property",
                    "Cloud",
                    "StringValue"
                ],
                "displayName": "Customer Name",
                "name": "CustomerName",
                "schema": "string"
            }
        ],
        "description": "Reports current temperature and provides desired temperature control.",
        "displayName": "Thermostat"
    }
}
```

[image]

- Then create Jobs with REST API IoT [Central](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/dataplane/jobs/create?view=rest-iotcentral-dataplane-2022-07-31&tabs=HTTP#cloudpropertyjobdata).

```http
PUT https://{your-app-subdomain}.azureiotcentral.com/api/jobs/{jobId}?api-version=2022-07-31
Authorization:  API tokens
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body:**

```json
{
  "displayName": "My Job",
  "group": "group1",
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "property",
      "target": "dtmi:contoso:mythermostattemplate;1",
      "path": "targetTemperature",
      "value": 90
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are getting issues while using this API. We are seeing too many requests error even when the threshold limit of 20 requests per second is not reached.

Comment: @AyushAgarwal Agarwal Throttling limits [is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/throttling#throttling-limits) 20 requests per second per application . So it limits set for API requests, such as 20 requests per second per application. we receive Too Many Requests in response

Comment: Yes, so we are not reaching that limit, still we are seeing 429 error.

Comment: The response includes a Retry-After value, it also specifies the number of seconds your application should wait (or sleep) before sending the next request. If you send a request before the retry value has elapsed, your request isn't processed and a new retry value is returned.